# Chaining reusable decorated tasks (taskflow api) airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I am currently experimenting with reusable airflow tasks.

I am basing my testing on the dags provided in the documentation of airflow

```
@task
def add_task(x, y):
    print(f"Task args: x={x}, y={y}")
    return x + y

@dag(start_date=DateTime(2022, 1, 1),schedule=None, catchup=False)
def mydag():
    start = add_task.override(task_id="start_0")(1, 2)
    for x, y, task_id_str in zip([1,3,5],[2,4,6],["start_1", "start_2", "start_3"], strict=True):
        start >> add_task.override(task_id=task_id_str)(x,y)

mydag()
```

Unfortunately with the current setup the tasks 1 to 3 are parallel.

Is there a way to chain those tasks as a downstream in a pythonic way?
e.g `t1 >> t2 >> t3` .. I can't seem to find any examples in the documentation.

Note, I do understand that I could use dynamic mapping, however, I want to see if I can do it without DM.

Resources:
https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/managing-dependencies

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#reusing-a-decorated-task

I am expecting an end result that would look similar to

```
t0.set_downstream(t1)
t1.set_downstream(t2)
t2.set_downstream(t3)
```

[parallel tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DwxO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`chain()` method described in that Astronomer Learn doc you referenced](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/managing-dependencies#using-chain). The trick is to create a list of the "start_*" tasks and then `chain()` the unpacked list.

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain


@task
def add_task(x, y):
    print(f"Task args: x={x}, y={y}")
    return x + y

@dag(start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),schedule=None, catchup=False)
def mydag():
    start = add_task.override(task_id="start_0")(1, 2)

    zip_tasks = []
    for x, y, task_id_str in zip([1,3,5],[2,4,6],["start_1", "start_2", "start_3"], strict=True):
        zip_tasks.append(add_task.override(task_id=task_id_str)(x,y))

    chain(start, *zip_tasks)

mydag()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :)  i will test it and mark it as an answer ASAP

Comment: Much appreciated :) !!! works like a charm